# Prevent python shelve corruption

Tags: python, shelve

How should I prevent corruption in a shelve file?  Should the shelve be closed most of the time and then opened only when I need to read or edit a value?

Comment: Don't use shelve. It corrupts. I suggest sqlite.

Comment: @nosklo agreed, it isn't particularly reliable and its use varies from platform to platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If safety of your persistent objects is of high importance in your project, using `shelve` is not a good idea. Neither is pickling objects and manually writing them into files.

Consider that real databases invest huge resources (brainpower and code) to be safe in case of failures. So keep your data in a real DB. The simplest would be `sqlite`, as it comes bundled with Python. `sqlite` is quite safe and has a lot of smarts in it about keeping your data in some valid state even in case of system failures (like when someone trips on your PC's power cable).

Comment: @metaguppy: shove looks like an interesting approach, being a frontend to other tools like sqlite and other DBs. I would consider using it, but since it's not well known I wouldn't place my most important data in it without some serious testing and research