# Flat file key-value store in python

Tags: python

I'm looking for a flat-file, portable key-value store in Python. I'll be using strings for keys and either strings or lists for values. I looked at ZODB but I'd like something which is more widely used and is more actively developed. Do any of the dmb modules in Python require system libraries or a database server (like mysql or the likes) or can I write to file with any of them?

If a dbm does not support a python lists, I imagine that I can just serialize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to ask an obvious question, but wouldn't a [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) file serve you just fine?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I actually need to do a lot of constant-time look-ups based off of keys (~thousands of keys, hundreds of thousands of lookups).

Comment: I actually ended up doing this except used multiple JSON files.

Comment: @daveslab: One should add that this is a good solution, when the data fits into memory. Then one basically needs some time for (de)serialization, but it would only been done once. After that, the [time complexity of dicts] (https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#dict) is what you get. You could probably add a short example code how to (de)serialize. (I could do that, too, if that's ok for you.)

Answer (score 7):

You may want to consider [h5py](http://alfven.org/wp/hdf5-for-python/) which is a Python interface to HDF5.

```
In [1]: import h5py

In [2]: f = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'w')

In [3]: f['abc'] = [1, 2, 3]

In [4]: f['d'] = 'hello'

In [5]: f.close()

In [6]: f2 = h5py.File('test.hdf5', 'r')

In [7]: f2['abc'].value
Out[7]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [8]: list(f2['abc'])
Out[8]: [1, 2, 3]

In [10]: f2['d'].value
Out[10]: 'hello'
```

Comment: Your code example doesn't work for me with h5py v3.6.0.
`In[7]` results in `AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'value'`.

Answer (score 5):

There is default support for sqlite and is included in standard library, but for sake of simplicity you can use shelve

http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html

edit:
I havent tested this, buy dbm might be soltion for you. It is key-value database on UNIX since 1979.

http://docs.python.org/library/anydbm.html#module-anydbm and in case you need serialisation you can use pickle.

Comment: Right, I looked at sqlite, but I need to make a bunch of constant-time look-ups and my need is more of what a key-value store offers. Edit: Also, I've heard some bad things about shelve's reliability.

Comment: Shelve is really the simplest choice if you all you want is a persistent key-store. Just be aware that it relies on pickle, so you have to use "pickleable" objects.

Comment: I've heard that shelve isn't the best for reliability: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226580/prevent-python-shelve-corruption
I'd like something with transaction support

Comment: dbm / anydbm sounds cool. it seems to be using bdhash which is based on BSD db. Is that included on all Unix installations? Is it the same as this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB?

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the `shelve` module.  It uses pickle under the hood, and allows you to create a key-value look up that persists between launches.

Additionally, the `json` module with `dump` and `load` methods would probably work pretty well as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've heard that shelve tends to not be as reliable. It's very important for data to not get corrupted for me.

Comment: @oxuser - can you site references to that effect?  I've _never_ encountered a problem with it.  I'd be interested in reviewing criticisms of the module, but I find it to be exceedingly convenient.

Comment: Sure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226580/prevent-python-shelve-corruption

Comment: Basically, I'd like something which can work transactionally.